# Attaching sensors to PCB to minimize space

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, sensor

[image]In my electronic product design project I need to come up with a completely finished product that can be presented in the market.What i'm designing is a turbidity meter with Arduino components with ATmega328P.My question is,as I'm designing this as a commercial product,I can't use pin headers and attach the sensors to the PCB using jumper cables.What would be  the good approaches to save up space and attach them well.Some  sensor (pads)surfaces are parallel and some are perpendicular to the PCB surface when attaching.

Comment: A photo of the "sensor"  in question would help. It's not uncommon to  use a cable and connector on the PCB, and often a small transition PCB on the remote device just to connect it to the cable. FPCs may be useful as well.

Comment: Only you know what the sensor is since you haven't told us. Why can't you: (a) mount the sensor directly on the PCB (b) mount the PCB directly on the sensor (c) use a flexible PCB  to connect sensor to main system?

Comment: with the limited info, I would say to make it more suitable as a commercial project, consider building your own PCB with the 328p on it, this will let you fit connectors that suit your purpose and be much more compact than the usual headers.

Comment: Can I also use some jumper wires along with the inclined pin headers,do you find it ok..Are there female pin headers with 90 degrees inclined cause I haven't seen any.I currently don't have enough resources to use a flexible PCB.